# using LINQ query to get max of a varchar column

Tags: sql-server, performance, linq

I have a `Code` column of type `varchar` in database, which includes numbers only. I use the method below to get the next code, and it works fine. But I prefer all the calculations and type conversions to be done on SQL side, to have less overhead. Using the code below, I retrieve all data, which is not needed. Any ideas is really appreciated.

```
public string GetNextCode(int type)
{
    var codeList = (from o in ObjectQuery
                     where o.Type == Type
                     select o.Code).ToList<string>();

    List<int> list = codeList.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    int nextDL = list.Max() + 1;

    return nextDL.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution I came up with:

```
var max = (from o in ObjectQuery                       
           let num = ObjectQuery.Where(i => i.Type == Type).Select(i => i.Code).Cast<int>().Max()
           select num).FirstOrDefault() + 1;

return max.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below, it orders the result set descending by the Code and then grabs the first result. Please note I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

```
var codeList = (from o in ObjectQuery
                     where o.Type == Type
                     select o.Code).OrderByDescending(
                             x => x.Code).First()
```

Instead of `OrderByDescending().First()` you could also use `OrderBy().Last()`

Comment: Oh, but this won't work, since for example `"111" < "99"` while `111 > 99`

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I read over the fact that it was a varchar rather than an int and orderBy would turn it alphabetical so 99 would be higher in the orderByDescending than 1000.